# SQL query to obtain trends in group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with SQL query

I have a table like this

```
Person     Scoring date      Score
--------------------------------------
Person1    20150818          9.5
Person1    20150817          8.5
Person1    20150816          6.5
Person2    20150818          5.5
Person2    20150817          8.5
Person2    20150816          7.5
Person3    20150818          8.5
Person3    20150817          8.5
Person3    20150816          6.5
```

I need to obtain results in this format

```
Person     Scoring date      Score  Current_flag  Trend  
--------------------------------------------------------
Person1    20150818          9.5       1            UP
Person1    20150817          8.5       0            null
Person1    20150816          6.5       0            null
Person2    20150818          5.5       1            DOWN
Person2    20150817          8.5       0            null
Person2    20150816          7.5       0            null
Person3    20150818          8.5       1            EQUAL
Person3    20150817          8.5       0            null
Person3    20150816          6.5       0            null
```

1. The most current flag must be at the newest date field.
2. The trend field compares the current field with the day before

Could someone help me with a query on my first table to obtain the second?

I tried something with the GROUP BY function but can't find the solution.

Thanks

Comment: What version of sql server?  If you are on 2014, the `lag` function can be used here.

Comment: Could you show us some code you have tried?

Comment: I use sql server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL server 2012+ version
then you can try the below query:

SQL fiddle for demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3ca38/4

```
select 
    Person, 
    Scoring_Date,
    Score, 
    current_flag, 
    CASE WHEN current_flag=1 then Trend else NULL end as Trend
from
(
    select 
      Person,
      Scoring_date,
      Score,
      case when MAX(scoring_date) over(partition by Person order by Person) =scoring_date
      then 1 else 0 end  
      as current_flag,
      case 
        when 
            LAG(score,1) over (partition by Person order by scoring_date)>score then 'DOWN' 
        when 
            LAG(score,1) over (partition by Person order by scoring_date)< score then 'UP' 
        when 
            LAG(score,1) over (partition by Person order by scoring_date)= score then 'EQUAL' 
        else 
            NULL
        end 
            as Trend
     from tbl
 ) tbl
 order by Person asc, scoring_date desc
```

For 2008 version try the below query as `LAG/LEAD` were not available in 2008 version
Sql fiddle for this version : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ca38/2

```
select 
        t.Person,
        t.scoring_date,
        t.score,
        t.current_flag,
        case 
            when 
                t2.score>t.score then 'DOWN' 
        when 
                t2.score<t.score then 'UP' 
        when 
                t2.score=t.score then 'EQUAL' 
        else 
            NULL
        end 
            as Trend
    from 
    (
        select 
          Person,
          Scoring_date,
          Score,
          case when MAX(scoring_date) over(partition by Person order by Person) =scoring_date
          then 1 else 0 end  
          as current_flag,
          RANK() over(partition by Person order by Person,Scoring_Date) as r
        from tbl
    ) t 
    left join 
    (
        select 
          Person,
          Scoring_date,
          Score,
          RANK() over(partition by Person order by Person,Scoring_Date) as r
        from tbl
    ) t2   
    on t.Person=t2.Person and 
    t.r-1=t2.r
    and t.current_flag=1
    order by Person asc, scoring_date desc
```

Comment: I use SQL server 2008 and the code doesnt seems to work

Comment: @NickH I've updated my answer. Please have a look. If you need any explanation let me know.I'll assist.

Comment: this helped me a lot ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Not everything but a proper start

```
with cte as 
(  select Person, Scoring date, Score, 
          row_number() over (partition by Person order by scoring date desc) as rn  
     from table 
)
select cte1.* 
  from cte as cte1  
  left join cte as cte2 
    on cte1.person = cte2.person 
   and cte1.rn = 1 
   and cte2.rn = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with window functions:

```
create table t(Person varchar(7), Scoring date, Score money)

insert into t values
('Person1', '20150818', 9.5),
('Person1', '20150817', 8.5),
('Person1', '20150816', 6.5),
('Person2', '20150818', 5.5),
('Person2', '20150817', 8.5),
('Person2', '20150816', 7.5),
('Person3', '20150818', 8.5),
('Person3', '20150817', 8.5),
('Person3', '20150816', 6.5);

with cte as(select *, 
                   row_number() 
                     over(partition by Person order by Scoring desc) rn from t)
select c1.Person, 
       c1.Scoring,
       c1.Score, 
       case when c1.Score > c2.Score then 'up'
            when c1.Score < c2.Score then 'down'
            when c1.Score = c2.Score then 'equal'
       end as Trend
from cte c1
left join cte c2 on c1.Person = c2.Person and c1.rn = 1 and c2.rn = 2
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f49e4/1